# RecyclerView display first item of the dynamic list only.

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a dynamic list of several name. But, the `RecyclerView` displays the first item of the list only. What can be done to solve that problem?

For `RecyclerView`

`routes_recyclerview.xml` includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.RoutesAssignActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_routes_assign"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For displaying the list name,

`routes_recycler_listview.xml` includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I includes header of the list. So, for header, I have

`view_header.xml` includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#001F3F"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.RoutesAssignActivity"
    />
```

This `getter and setter` method for routes class:

`Routes.jave` includes:

```
public class Routes{
   @SerializedName("assignDate")
    private String assignDate;
    @SerializedName("routeName")
    private String routeName;
  
    public String  getAssignDate() {
        return assignDate;
    }
    public void setAssignDate(String assignDate) {
        this.assignDate = assignDate;
    }

    public String getRouteName() {
        return routeName;
    }

    public void setRouteName(String routeName) {
        this.routeName = routeName;
    }
}
```

To list the total routes, i have `RoutesList.java`. Here,

```
public class RoutesList implements Comparable<RoutesList>{

    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("routes")
    private List<Routes> routes = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getDateString() {
        return date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        try {
            return format.parse(getDateString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<Routes> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(List<Routes> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull RoutesList another) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(another.getDateString());
            return date.compareTo(getDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In my `RecyclerViewRecyclerAdapter.java`, i have:
At `ViewHolder` i use:

```
public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
```

At `onCreateViewHolder` method, i use:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        this.context = parent.getContext();
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.routes_recycler_listview, parent, false));
    }
```

At `onBindViewHolder` method, i use:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.textView.setText(item.getRoutes().get(position).getRouteName());

    }
```

At `RoutesAssignActivity.java` class, i use :

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this).build());
        adapter = new StickyHeaderListView(routes,this);
        final StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration headersDecor = new StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(headersDecor);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After all, i only get this:

[image]

How do i get all name in list ?

Comment: please post the code that set adapter and routelist data in your activity/fragment?

Comment: `holder.textView.setText(item.getRoutes().get(position).getRouteName());` This is what i use at `onBindViewHolder` method to display all items in the list at `RecyclerViewRecyclerAdapter.java` . But it display the first item only .